# How can single user registration and login work for separate Laravel applications

Tags: php, laravel, user-registration

I need to set up a single user registration and login page to work for separate Laravel applications or projects, such that if a user registers on the first application, he or she can use that profile to login into the other application without needing to register again on the second application.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic approach would be to connect both projects to the same database, and make sure they both have the same application key (the `APP_KEY` entry) set in the `.env` file, as this is what is used for the `EncryptionServiceProvider`.

A more complete, and thought-through approach would be to implement some form of Single Sign On (SSO) in both projects. Something such as [zefy/laravel-sso](https://github.com/zefy/laravel-sso) could be a good starting point.

Yet another option, if it fits your usecase, might be to implement Social Authentication instead. Each project would maintain their own record of users, but since authentication would happen via third parties, that might not matter. [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite) might be a good starting point for this.

Comment: With this will a user registered in the first application be also able to login into the second application without the need to register in the second app. What about the issue of the Laravel version, must both laravel instance be the same version

Comment: @iamdeed They would be sharing the same encryption and databases, so they should be able to, yes. The system hasn't changed much lately, but I wouldn't connect two projets to the same database without ensuring they're both at the same version, at all times.

Do note that the proper way of doing this is in the second paragraph: Implementing SSO. The first approach is more of a hack, than a thought-through solution.

Comment: I will also explore Socialite, but would rather use the first option as both applications will be sub-domains on the same root domain.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to ensure that in the other applications there is an authentication to the database or services warehousing the user credentials your application should be able to reach this endpoint and check if that user is already authenticated/validated/signed
you can check

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-laravel-login-authentication/